# How to implement a swift delegate method in objective-C having parameter?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a swift protocol having following delegate method

```
@objc public protocol CuteDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    @objc func myCuteFunc(name: NSString)
}
```

I have declared delegate object in swift as well

```
weak var delegate : CuteDelegate?
```

In my objective C controller where I am implementing the above delegate method is as follows

```
-(void)myCuteFunc:(NSString* )name{

}
```

But while calling the method in swift controller

```
 self.delegate?.myCuteFunc(name: str as NSString)
```

I get **unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Any clue what's the issue

Comment: Can you share your declaration of `delegate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to account for the first arguments's name:

**Either:**

1. Make your Objective-C function `-(void)myCuteFuncWithName:(NSString* )name`

**Or:**

2. Change your protocol to `@objc func myCuteFunc(_ name: NSString)` and call it with `self.delegate?.myCuteFunc(str)`

This is just an artifact of the way Objective-C function names work vs. the way Swift names its arguments. Objective-C has no way of naming the first argument (which is usually described by the function name), so if Swift has a label for the first argument, the convention used is to add `With` plus the argument name (with the argument name capitalized) to the function name. By adding `_`, you make the first argument unnamed and that translates better to the Objective-C naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for saving my day but still wondering why _ name: needed , if you could explain?

Comment: It's just an artifact of the way Objective-C works vs. the way Swift names its arguments. Objective-C has no way of naming the first argument, so if Swift has one, the convention used is to add `With` plus the argument name with the argument name capitalized.  By adding `_`, you make the first argument unnamed, so that translates better to the Objective-C naming convention.